# How to determine the maximum id of a set of tables in my database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to determine the maximum Id int value for a set of tables in my database.  The column is always 'Id' and is the primary key.  Is there a simple way I can make this determination without resorting to a cursor or looping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(MaxId) As MaxId FROM (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS MaxId FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(id) AS MaxId FROM Table2
) AS T1
```

Comment: +1.  This is what I was thinking.  I think this would be the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

could you create a sp_excutesql query for something like?

```
select max(id) from (
    select id from t1
    union all
    select id from t2
    union all
    select id from t3)
```

Possibly by putting the table names into a temp table/cte to start with?

Actually think there is a loop happening.